# Bar Plot with 3 independent variables in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My df looks like this:

```
Training_Task <- c("Imag", "Imag", "Imag", "Imag", "Rephrasing", "Rephrasing", "Rephrasing", "Rephrasing")
emotionality <- c("emo", "neu", "emo", "neu", "emo", "neu", "emo", "neu")
target_type <- c("novel", "novel", "pseudo", "pseudo", "novel", "novel", "pseudo", "pseudo")
acc <- c(93, 95, 97, 98, 96, 94, 92, 90)
df <- data.frame(Training_Task, emotionality, target_type, acc)
```

Now I would like to create a bar plot that looks somehow like this:

```
plot = ggplot(df, aes(fill =Training_Task, y=acc, x=target_type))
```

But I would like the IV emotionality to be added by emotional bars (emotionality = emo) being saturated and neutral bars (emotionality = neu) being pale.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `alpha` in your aesthetic and set position to `dodge`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Training_Task, y=acc, x=target_type, alpha = emotionality), stat = 'identity', position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1,0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked out well, but I wanted to add error bars which I do not get to work here, because it doesn't take the "fill" argument in the geom_errorbar command, which is why the error bars for both training tasks are on top of each other. My df has another column se and I tried to add ```geom_errorbar(aes(x = target_type, alpha=emotionality, fill = Training_Task, ymin=acc - se, ymax=acc+se), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))```. Do you have an idea on that? Sorry to bother you